# Pandas: How to get unique values counted by two indexes

Tags: python, pandas

I need to find month by month way of showing year to date unique values. For example:

```
month   value
1       a
1       b
1       a

2       a
2       a
2       a

3       c
3       b
3       b

4       d
4       e
4       f
```

Should output:

```
Month   Monthly unique  Year to date unique
1       2               2
2       1               2
3       2               3
4       3               6
```

For monthly unique it is just a matter of group by and unique(), but it won't work for year-to-date this way. Year-to-date may be achieved by using for loop and filtering dataframe month by month since the beginning of the year, but it's slow, non-pythonic way I want to omit.

How to do it in efficient way?

Comment: @MHanif, if you have the answer, it would be better to post an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us do

```
s = df.groupby('month').value.agg(['nunique',list])
s['list'] = s['list'].cumsum().map(lambda x : len(set(x)))
s
       nunique  list
month               
1            2     2
2            1     2
3            2     3
4            3     6
```

Answer (score 5):

BEN_YO's approach is pretty simple and effective for small datasets. However, it can be slow and costly on big dataframe due to `cumsum` on lists (of strings).

Let's try `drop_duplicates` first and only work on duplicates:

```
(df.drop_duplicates(['month','value'])
   .assign(year=lambda x: ~x.duplicated(['value']))
   .groupby('month')
   .agg({'value':'nunique', 'year':'sum'})
   .assign(year=lambda x: x.year.cumsum())
)
```

Output:

```
       value  year
month             
1          2     2
2          1     2
3          2     3
4          3     6
```

Comment: This approach counts month values properly (and 6 times faster than @BEN_YO's), but aggregated values for the year are for sure wrong. Data output in year should be never lower than in value and the same in the first month. My first three months look like:
      value  year
month             
1          123291     35867
2          113240     71225
3          80661     98136
which by definition is wrong. I checked input columns several times.